# Spring WebSocket can't send message to authenticated user when pass jwtToken in header

Tags: websocket

## 1. scenes to be used

- When connect WebSocket is permitAll
- Then Subscribe **/user/queue/userInfo** need user authenticated
- After subscribe success, send to **/app/user/info** need authenticated(Because I need get userInfo ), and push message to  current user subscribe queue **/user/queue/userInfo**

Answer (score 0):

### 2.1 Details description after I trace the source code

1) when subscribe **/user/queue/userInfo** with the jwtToken in header, I get the jwtToken, then get Principle user object from auth server with jwtToken, then set user in StompHeaderAccessor.
At last, the user subscribe lookupDestination is /queue/userInfo/user{sessionId}
2) Then send **/app/user/userInfo** with jwtToken in header, after handle the return value,
the final send destination is /user/{Principle.getName()}/queue/userInfo.

the user never subscribe this queue: /user/{Principle.getName()}/queue/userInfo, and the message cannot send to user